# What are twisted Verma modules? Basic properties?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, lie-algebras, d-modules, geometric-representation-theory

Let $\mathfrak{g}$ be a simple Lie algebra over $\mathbf{C}$, $\lambda$ be a weight in the nonnegative Weyl chamber and $w_1,w_2\in W$. Then the *twisted* Verma modules are defined e.g. in Andersen and Lauritzen's ["Twisted Verma modules"](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0105012),
$$M_\lambda(w_1,w_2)$$
which are objects in category $\mathcal{O}_{w_2\cdot \lambda}$. Loosely speaking, they are meant to interpolate between the Verma and dual Verma modules as you vary $w_1,w_2$. However, I'm having troubles translating their definition into language I can understand.

My **questions** are:

1. What is the definition of $M_\lambda(w_1,w_2)$ in Beilinson-Bernstein terms, as D modules on $G/B$?
2. What is the complete list of maps between them? For instance, for $\mathfrak{sl}_2$ there are short exact sequences

$$L_0\to M_0^\vee \to M_{-2} \hspace{15mm}M_{-2}\to M_{0}\to L_0$$

involving the (dual) Verma modules. I assume in general we get a canonical injection/surjection every time we vary $(w_1,w_2)$ suitably.

3. Is there a categorical characterisation of twisted Vermas (e.g. "they are the projective objects satisfying ...").

References would be appreciated (and I think these questions are not answered in the reference I linked above)?

Answer (score 2):

Answer to 1 **but not to 2 or 3**.

---

*Setup*: Let $\lambda\in \mathfrak{t}^*$ be any integral weight, $\mathcal{L}(\lambda)\in \text{Pic}(G/B)$ the associated line bundle,  $\mathcal{D}_\lambda$ for twisted differential operators, and $\chi_\lambda:Z(U(\mathfrak{g}))\to k$ the associated central character (so $\chi_0$ kills all basis elements except $1$). In particular, by Beilinson-Bernstein localisation
$$\mathcal{D}_\lambda\text{-Mod}\ \simeq\ U(\mathfrak{g})/\ker\chi_{\lambda-\rho}\text{-Mod}.$$

---

*Answer*: Pick a pair of elements of the Weyl group $v,w\in W$, use the first to make
$$\mathcal{L}(v\cdot \lambda)\ \in \ \mathcal{D}_{w\cdot \lambda}\text{-Mod}.$$
and the second to make the Bruhat cell
$$i_{w}\ : \ X_{w}\ \hookrightarrow\ G/B.$$
Putting these together, we can form the pull back $i_w^!\mathcal{L}(v\cdot\lambda)$ as $v\cdot\lambda$ twisted D modules. Taking global sections,
$$\text{Twisted Verma module }(v,w)\ =\ \text{a shift of }\text{H}^\bullet(i_w^!\mathcal{L}(v\cdot\lambda)).$$

---

This cohomology of $i_{w*}i_w^!\mathcal{L}(v\cdot\lambda)$ on $G/B$ is called the *local cohomology*, and you can show that it is concentrated in degree $2\ell(w)$, and we shift to make the twisted Verma sit in degree zero. It is a representation of $\mathfrak{g}$ on which the centre $Z(U(\mathfrak{g}))$ acts by the character $\chi_\lambda=\chi_{v\cdot\lambda}$.